# Uncaught Error: Module name "express" has not been loaded yet for context: _

Tags: javascript, node.js

Im working with Node.js and im getting this error

```
Uncaught Error: Module name "express" has not been loaded yet for context: _
```

https://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded
    at makeError (require.js:168)
    at localRequire (require.js:1436)
    at VM29 app.js:3
    at Object.execCb (require.js:1696)
    at Module.check (require.js:883)
    at Module.enable (require.js:1176)
    at Module.init (require.js:788)
    at require.js:1460

```
app.js

require(['require'], function (require) {
var client = require('express'); // <-ERROR
app = client();
});
```

_Layout.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/modernizr-2.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/popper.min.js" type="module"></script>
<script data-main="app" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.3.6/require.js"></script>
<script src="~/app.js"></script>
```

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Test Subscribe to Newsletter</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="Index">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="Admin">Admin</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

</div>

@RenderBody()
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Package.json

```
{
"name": "test3",
"version": "1.0.0",
"private": true,
"description": "test program",
"main": "index.js",
"dependencies": {
"amd-loader": "0.0.8",
"common.js": "^1.1.1",
"express": "^4.17.1",
"express-cdn": "^0.4.0",
"expressjs": "^1.0.1",
"requirejs": "^2.3.6"
},
"devDependencies": {},
"scripts": {
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
},
"type": "module",
"author": "trikam",
"license": "ISC"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read the page that comes attached with the error. `express` has not been loaded in your top level require, so you have to change

```js
require(['require']
```

to

```js
require(['require', 'express']
```

then you can freely `require("express")` in your code.

Comment: Im getting this error now

require.js:1961 GET http://localhost:57743/express.js 
net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Comment: You realize `express` is a server-side module and isn't meant to be required from the client, right?

Comment: i have a test for a company and they want a node.js application, i cant find resources on how to work with mvc and node.js not sure where to look i googled and find nothing from scratch

Comment: `require.js` is a client side module, and it looks like you're not even using node at all.

Comment: [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gG3pytAY2MY) and [here](https://www.creativebloq.com/how-to/get-started-with-expressjs).